# Visual Studio Code select file content run in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Like this, Select a row, Right-click and run it from the terminal

[image]

I try to use `code-runner extension`, But it's going to generate one `tempCodeRunnerFile.sh`, This is not a good solution

Comment: Why .sh file isn't a good solution.

Normally, I create .sh file, add the code and run it. And I didn't use any extension for this thing.

Comment: The code-runner extension can select the contents of .sh file,
generate ```tempCoderUnnerFile.sh``` and run ```tempCoderUnnerFile.sh``` on the terminal.

but generating a ```tempCoderUnnerFile.c``` in the C project is not a wise choice,
and I don't like generating a tempCoderUnnerFile.sh file.